# How to override applicationContext.getId() with spring boot 2.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We have recently upgraded to spring boot 2.0 and noticed that the application context IDs aren't unique any more.  Previously, if we set `spring.application.index`, `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer` would use that to construct the application context id.  I now see that in spring 2.0, [the implementation was significantly changed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/2059922735fc157eac6cce6a5ab669e826f79bfb#diff-396dfef2caa69c1b8d48438ddee758e6). How best should id be set?  The goal is to include the hostname as part of the id to keep systems distinct.  The spring cloud docs still refer to the old way: [Service ID Must Be Unique](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_service_id_must_be_unique).

**UPDATE**
What used to happen is that `spring.application.name` was set in the source code of the project (ie my-app) and `spring.application.index` would be set in the runtime (ie, 1e4f630be), then `applicationContext.id` would have the value of `my-app-1e4f630be`.  Now, it always has the value of `my-app-1`.  The implemenation of [ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java) no longer references `spring.application.index`.  This is a significant change between versions and I haven't found examples or documentation on how to customize the id properly with spring boot 2.0

Comment: Have you considered setting `spring.application.name` and including the hostname in its value?

Comment: By default, spring cloud uses `spring.application.name` to identify instances of a service as being of the same type. Also by default, we create an instance id using `${spring.application.name}:${hostname}:${spring.application.instance_id:${server.port}}`. So it should be unique. Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: @spencergibb that sounds like what used to be the code in spring boot 1.5, but it is different in 2.0

Comment: @AndyWilkinson i can try that, it seemed like a work around.  I was hoping that we could set spring.application.name would have the true name of my applications (myapp), but then the ID would be unique, ie myapp:machine1 or myapp:machine2

Comment: @pgreen2 it's what the code does now. You haven't said what is happening.

Comment: @spencergibb are we talking about the same version?  I'm looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java which no longer uses the code which you mention.

Comment: No, I'm looking at a class IdUtils in spring cloud commons that attempts to create a unique instance id.

Comment: Quoting `https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-consul.adoc#making-the-consul-instance-id-unique`: "By default, the Spring Application Context ID is ${spring.application.name}:comma,separated,profiles:${server.port}". Is there a possibility to have this documented behaviour implemented? I'd like to overwrite the contextId but not the applicationName.